# Unable to append javascript with document.body.appendChild

Tags: javascript, chromium

I'm trying to append javascript to a loaded page by:

```
var sc = document.createElement('script');
sc.content = "<script>alert('aa')</script>";
document.body.appendChild (sc);
```

But that didn't work in chromium:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't put `<script>...</script>` inside the *content* of a `script` element. But more to the point, I don't think they have a `content` property (I [don't see one here](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-81598695), for instance).

If I recall correctly, the most reliable way to put content within a `script` element at runtime is via [`createTextNode`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1975348127) and [`appendChild`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-184E7107), e.g.: [Live example](http://jsbin.com/igasil) | [source](http://jsbin.com/igasil/edit)

```
var sc = document.createElement('script');
sc.appendChild(document.createTextNode("alert('aa')"));
document.body.appendChild(sc);
```

...but I wouldn't be surprised to find that some older browsers required you to set `innerText` or something instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.appendChild(document.createTextNode("alert('http://jsfiddle.net/UpWhX/')"));
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Try this [TestHere](http://jsfiddle.net/UpWhX/2/) `http://jsfiddle.net/UpWhX/2/`